# Centered <div> is not exactly center, why?

Tags: html, css

First off, please excuse my ignorance, I have not played with HTML in almost 14 years and I'm trying to familiarize myself with new standards, and revisions. I have a layout that I'm currently experimenting with, and my container block element does not seem to be absolutely centered horizontally. unfortunately I have no idea why this is happening, and I was hoping one of you could either identify what is wrong, or explain why this behavior is happening.

Thanks!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<div class="container">

    <div id="contentMain">

        <div class="titleBar">
            <p>Main Content Title Element @ 960px</p>
        </div>

        <div class="containerContent">
            <p>Main Content Area Element</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#F00;
    min-width:996px;
    width:2px;
}

.containerContent {
    padding:4px;
}

.titleBar {
    padding:4px;
}

#contentMain {
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
    border:1px dashed #000;
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    width:960px;
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
}

p {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Comment: It takes *all* of this code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/74ngf/2/ (reduced code)

Comment: can you tell me which `div` from your code is not center aligned?

Comment: It's the dashed bordered one. But looking on this (slightly modified) version, the problem is kind of obvious: http://jsfiddle.net/74ngf/5/

Comment: Sorry I was just trying to include everything to be safe.

Comment: Next time, you should try to reduce the amount of code to the minimum code that reproduces the error. You might then either find the error yourself during this process, or at least make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Edited the initial post to reflect minimal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.container` divs are perfectly centered, but their content does not fill their whole width.

Have a look on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74ngf/5/

As you can see, the container has a red background, which stretches beyond its content. To solve the problem, you need to manually get the content's width correct, e.g.:

```
#contentMain {
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
    border:1px dashed #000;
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    width:986px; /* this is the important part */
    height:200px;
    clear:both;
}
```

(updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74ngf/8/)

**Where do the `986px` come from?**

The container has a width of `996px`. `#contentMain` has a left and right margin of `4px`, and a border width of `1px` on both sides. If it should fill the container horizontally, it therefor has to have a width of `(996 - 2*4 - 2*1) px` which is `986px`.

Or you might consider using a different layout approach, as Chanckjh supposed.

Comment: Can I ask why you used 986 vise the width of the container? I know I have to take certain elements into concideration, I'm just trying to understand it further. It has been a minute since I have seriously approached HTML and CSS.

Comment: I've added an explanation to illustrate the number.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to center the child divs is using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`

Give the parent div `text-align: center` and the child divs `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/nS6tL/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.block{
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work exactly as intended. Thanks you. I was wondering if there is any other way to align the contents of a <div> without using text-align. I guess it is just personal preference, but I would rather use text attributes for text, although I have yet to see an align attribute specific to the <div> contents for non-text items. Mind you I'm also trying to minimize extra code required for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can center your div by simple method using `margin-left:auto;` `margin-right:auto;` if your container width is fixed

```
<div class="container">
    Text and container both are center align
</div>


.container {
    width:80%;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:150px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/2uBQK/1/)

Comment: This does not work as I would like. The text-align section centers all the text across the <div>'s contained within the container, and it does not seem to affect the position of the <div>'s specifically.

Comment: if you remove `text-align:center` it will align your text to left as it is default text alignment but giving `width` and `margin` align div to the center